# Segfault trying to access array

Tags: c++, arrays, segmentation-fault

I am trying to keep track of a particular counter as I run through a series of loops.

Essentially I am looping over some input files, during which some calculations are done on each file. Outside the file loop I have declared an array to keep track of a particular set of integers, which are all zero for the first file but then get added too as calculations with successive files are done. When I try to update this 'tracker array' it segfaults halfway through (there are several elements for each file) on all but the first file runthrough. See code below:

The array in question is originally initialized here:

```
int* TempRowLength = new int[PrimeDatL];
for(int i=0;i<PrimeDatL;i++){
  TempRowLength[i]=0; 
}
```

and the segfault occurs in the following section:

```
int tempArrayN;
cout<<"Begin pHi2 comp:"<<endl;
for(int j=0;j<PrimeDatL;j++){
  int i=0;
  tempArrayN=TempRowLength[j]+1;
  cout<<tempArrayN<<endl;
  while(i<PHLengths[n]) {   
    tempArray1[0][j]=PrimeDat1[j];
    if(pHi1[0][i]==PrimeDat1[j]&&tempArrayN-1<PrimeDat2[j]) {
      tempArray1[tempArrayN][j]=pHi1[1][i];
      tempArrayN++;
    }
    i++;
  }
  TempRowLength[j]=TempRowLength[j]+tempArrayN;
}
```

The error occurs when I include the final line where I increase the value of TempRowLength. This does not happen if this declaration occurs earlier, but that makes it useless. Additionally, it only occurs after a few iterations of 'j' (j=6 causes the error).

I'm at a bit of a loss, I have declared the array and set aside memory where ever I have needed it, yet clearly I  have faux pas'ed somewhere with my pointers.

All help appreciated!

Comment: Note: you can avoid the first zeroing loop by saying `int* TempRowLength = new int[PrimeDatL]();`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a memory issue somewhere, possibly a buffer overrun. The easiest option might be to use `valgrind` to pinpoint the problem(s).